# Converting Date Format Of JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I have a JQuery Date Picker link to a HTML Form textbox. It enters the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. What I need is to convert this format to dd-mm-yyyy.

Can I do when the date just inserted or after inserted? If one or both can how can I do that?

I already tried the belo code. But it didn't work.

```
//Date Picker
$(function() {
    $("#to_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date() },);
    $("#from_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date() });
    $("div.ui-datepicker").css( { "font-size": "10px" } );
    $("#to_date").datepicker({ dateformat: "dd-mm-yyyy" }).val();
    $("#from_date".datepicker({ dateformat: "dd-mm-yyyy" }).val();
});
```

The above also contains the statements to display the last day to select as today.

So what is with my code?

Thanks & regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: That format won't convert your date the way you want, instead it will just set a format to be used on that control.

Comment: You need to convert what you get as a value from the control, into the date format you need

Comment: Do u want the format to be change once after u selected the date in date picker..

Comment: Yep that's fine what I want! So how am I going to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/4a6Uv/)

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#format" ).change(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
});
});
```

See the fiddle.. i think this would help you

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using format, it won't convert your date, instead it will just set a format to be used on that control.

So, you'l have to set format using `/` as you want it in `mm/dd/yyyy`

And, using javascript you have to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy`

So,

```
$(function() {
    $("#to_date").datepicker({ dateformat: "mm/dd/yyyy" });

});
```

Now while accessing it, you can convert it as following code:

```
var dt=$("#to_date").val();
var arr=dt.split("/");
var converted= arr[1]+"-"+arr[0]+"-"+arr[2];
console.log(converted);
```

Answer (score 0):

dateformat is probably case sensitive and should be dateFormat http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

```
$(function() {
    $("#to_date, #from_date").datepicker({  
        maxDate: new Date(),
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy"
    });
    $("div.ui-datepicker").css( { "font-size": "10px" } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code. Jquery options are case sensitive. So use **dateFormat** instead of **dateformat**. The format should be **dd-mm-yy** instead of **dd-mm-yyyy**

```
$(function() {
     $("#from_date, #to_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(), dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
     $("div.ui-datepicker").css( { "font-size": "10px" } );
});
```